# Spark-submit job performance

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark

I am currently running spark-submit on the following environment:

**Single node** (**RAM**: 40GB, **VCores**: 8, **Spark Version**: 2.0.2, **Python**: 3.5)

My pyspark program basically will read one **450MB** unstructured file from HDFS. Then it will loop through each lines and grab the necessary data and place it list. Finally it will use createDataFrame and save the data frame into Hive table.

My pyspark program code snippet:

```
sparkSession = (SparkSession
.builder
.master("yarn")
.appName("FileProcessing")
.enableHiveSupport()
.config("hive.exec.dynamic.partition", "true")
.config("hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode", "nonstrict")
.getOrCreate())

lines = sparkSession.read.text('/user/test/testfiles').collect()

for line in lines:
    // perform some data extrating and place it into rowList and colList using normal python operation

df = sparkSession.createDataFrame(rowList, colList)

df.registerTempTable("tempTable")
sparkSession.sql("create table test as select * from tempTable");
```

My spark-submit command is as the following:

```
spark-submit --master yarn --deploy-mode cluster --num-executors 2 --driver-memory 4g --executor-memory 8g --executor-cores 3 --files /usr/lib/spark-2.0.2-bin-hadoop2.7/conf/hive-site.xml FileProcessing.py
```

It took around 5 minutes to complete the processing. Is the performance consider good? How can I tune it in terms of setting the executor memory and executor cores so that the process can complete within 1-2 minutes, is it possible?

Appreciate your response. Thanks.

Comment: How long did it take to read the file?

Comment: I think at least got 2++ mins. Any way for us to track the log to find out the exact time for the read process?

Comment: Take a look at the spark user interface and see how long each stage took for that job.

Comment: Try without collect().

Comment: is this python code? I am not sure why you are using for loop. use map() on RDD to ransform something on each line.

Comment: A very basic answer to 'is this performance good' can be found by letting python doing the actual work without pySpark (load, process, store). That gives you a reference for how long things should take.

Comment: When you call collect() you pull the data into the driver and are no longer using spark.  Get rid of that collect call and do the processing on the cluster with spark instead of the local python process.

Comment: Thanks all for the responses. I am getting more idea from all of your response now. So based on the pyspark code that i am writing, when i loop it line by line, the processing will be using the local python instead of spark processing, right? I am not using pyspark transformation because of the complexity of the code with a lots of if else condition. I will try to change the program to use spark process instead. Thanks all.

Comment: Is pyspark suitable for unstructured data processing? Because sometimes for unstructured data, you will need to go through line by line and a lot of regex pattern matching and follow by extract the data and format it. As of now, for all these operations, i am using normal python code to perform it within pyspark application. Anyone have the similar use case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For tuning you application you need to know few things

1) You Need to Monitor your application whether your cluster is under utilized or not how much resources are used by your application which you have created

Monitoring can be done using various tools eg. Ganglia From Ganglia you can find CPU, Memory and Network Usage.

2) Based on Observation about CPU and Memory Usage you can get a better idea what kind of tuning is needed for your application

Form Spark point of you

In spark-defaults.conf

you can specify what kind of serialization is needed how much Driver Memory and Executor Memory needed by your application even you can change Garbage collection algorithm.

Below are few Example you can tune this parameter based on your requirements

```
spark.serializer                 org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer
spark.driver.memory              5g
spark.executor.memory            3g
spark.executor.extraJavaOptions  -XX:MaxPermSize=2G -XX:+UseG1GC
spark.driver.extraJavaOptions    -XX:MaxPermSize=6G -XX:+UseG1GC
```

For More details refer http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/tuning.html

Hope this Helps!!